# 4 scenes from Total Recall: original vs. remake

Tags: effects, total-recall-2012, remake, total-recall

I would like to know if the [2012 *Total Recall* remake](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386703/) captures some of the most significant and memorable scenes and effects from the [1990 original](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100802/). The particular ones I'm interested in are:

1. The Arnold low-gravity buggy eyeballs.
2. The three-breasted woman.
3. The mini Siamese twin alien.
4. The full-body disguise.

Were these included in the remake, and, if so, how were they presented?

Comment: bug eyes - no. 3 boobs - yes, small alien - no, full body disguise - not used by main character, but included as an homage. Just watch the movie. It's not the original, it's a completely different movie.

Comment: The new version of the movie has it's own good points but it just wasn't as fun as the original. Kate Beckinsale is always easy on the eyes, and the three-boobed gal looked more realistic than the old....but no Mars, no midget, no siamese Quatto, and the full body disguise idea turned out to be electro-optical...instead of mechanical.

Comment: I have tried to reword the question a little in order to remove the opinionated parts and concentrate on the essence of the question. In its current form I think it is a valid and interesting comparative question. +2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, you **cannot really expect the remake to capture the cult factor of the original**. In 2012 you can't expect this movie to be the hilarious "Verhoeveny" 80s/90s Arnie vehicle that the original is. A large factor to *Total Recall*'s attraction nowadays comes not only from being a gripping science-fiction action movie with an interesting story about memory distortion, but also largely due to its appeal as an entertaining Arnie movie with the usually exaggeratedly trashy/hilarious effects expected from Paul Verhoeven. While the remake tries to capture the former aspects (and *IMHO* largely succeeds in this endeavour), it neither can't nor wants to capture the latter aspects. It is an (*IMHO* entertaining) **modern science-fiction action blockbuster** with some interesting ideas (e.g. the whole *Fall* concept) and an appealing (even if not overly unique) visual style (that might *in its best moments* even be a little reminiscent of *Blade Runner*), not less but also not more.

That being said, let's take a look at the specific scenes you mentioned:

1. The story is neither set on Mars (but on a largely devastated earth split into two societies) nor is it a "Verhoeveny" 1990 flick, as said, so **no hilariously trashy eyeball effects**.
2. The **three-breasted woman is indeed in the remake**, albeit at an earlier part in the story (WARNING: picture contains nudity):

   > [image]
3. Mutants (let alone aliens) don't play much of a role in this movie if I remember correctly, so **no weird stomach mutants** either.
4. The famous **"two weeks lady" is paid tribute in the remake** but in a slightly different and, as fitting to the overall style of the movie less hilarious, form. The full-body disguise is a bit different and more hologram-based than suit-based, but a woman similar to the "two weeks lady" has a little cameo, as can also be seen in this clip from the movie:

Answer (score -1):

If it was a stand-alone, and wasn't judged by subjective viewers comparing it to the original: it's not *bad*.

First-off, the jpeg you're looking for (and answer to #2: '*yes*', but less-featured):
[image]

Unfortunately, #1- no time spent on Mars/lacking-atmosphere- no.

For #3, Quatro- yes:
[image]

Comment: Ha, I was looking for a gif of the new version (will edit to clarify). But these bring me back. What a great movie.

Comment: @SamtheBrand Ack!  Thought it was new.  The quality tricked me ;)  Hold on.

Comment: Your images are from the original, I think the asker was looking for how those things were done in the remake. Likewise point 3 is wrong, Quatto is *not* part of the remake. And you might also want to adress point 4.